# Facebook app review for API permissions still rejected

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Our web application aims to allow our users to share photos with comments directly from our platform.

Since May 10, I have made several permission requests from Facebook for the following permissions:

- pages_manages_posts
- pages_show_list
- instagram_content_publish
- pages_reads_engagement
- ads_management
- instagram_basic

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fv83sv8Z7EVmTEuNrIaVCpcYnHKY5H4A/view?usp=sharing

As and when requests some pass others not. In addition, our web application has not undergone any change since the first request, since everything has been working on our side from the beginning. And yet some permission seems to be released randomly as the different requests.

We only have the "instagram content publish" permission left, however as it always resulted in a refusal, we changed our Facebook developer account. Indeed, our new developer Facebook account has a company verification and we thought it would have more weight then.

However, on the first request on this other account, all permissions were denied, while there was only one left on the other application. And again, nothing had been touched on our web application.

We don't know what to do anymore because we can't get in touch with anyone.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? How to get in touch with an engineer / developer at Facebook?